# Visual Studio 2013 crashes when attempting to save an .rpt file modified in Crystal Reports 2013

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

We are experiencing an issue that occurs intermittently. I open, modify, and save existing .rpt files in Crystal Reports 2013.  Visual Studio 2013 crashes after opening the same file, making changes, and attempting to save.

It issue occurs on these machines:

1) Windows 7 Pro with SP1, Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, SAP Crystal Reports for Visual Studio version 13.10.1385.

2) Windows 8.1 Pro, Visual Studio 2013 Pro, SAP Crystal Reports for Visual Studio version 13.0.15.1840, Crystal Reports 2013.

Did some research and tried the solution to remove XML files from c:\temp, but it did not fix the problem.  I also attempted to alter the file permissions to allow 'Everyone' Full Control.  Anyone else experience the same problem and can shed light on how to fix?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Discovered a work-around to this problem and wanted to post in case someone else runs in to the same problem:  1) Open the report in Visual Studio 2013

2) Make edits, click the save icon/Ctrl+s.

3) When it does not save after the 1st click, select Menu -> Crystal Reports -> Preview Report, then save.

Answer (score 6):

just in the preview mode uncheck the "save data in the report" checkbox

[image]

Answer (score 4):

1. Open the report in Visual Studio 2013.
2. Make edits, click the save icon or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>.
3. Select Menu -> Crystal Reports -> Preview Report, then save.

Comment: Thank you @Benoit. This has bugged me for days!